# Running Selenium Tests on Linux using GeckoDriver: driver is not executable

Tags: java, linux, selenium, firefox, geckodriver

I am currently working on a test automation project using Selenium WebDriver on a Linux machine. (Ubuntu 16.04.3) Tests can be executed without any errors on a Windows machine, since I am trying to run the tests on a Linux VM I encountered critical issues while initializing the GeckoDriver.

Here is part of my code:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", _GECKO_DRIVER);
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

The variable _GECKO_DRIVER is the file path to a linux executable, I downloaded from this mirror: https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases (inside tar.gz folder)

Unfortunately JAVA is not able to initialize the driver, so tests can not be run and it results in following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
The driver is not executable: path/to/repo/./src/main/resources/Driver/GeckoDriver/geckodriver
at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:534)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.checkExecutable(DriverService.java:140)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.findExecutable(DriverService.java:131)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.GeckoDriverService.access$100(GeckoDriverService.java:41)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.GeckoDriverService$Builder.findDefaultExecutable(GeckoDriverService.java:115)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.build(DriverService.java:329)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.toExecutor(FirefoxDriver.java:207)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:103)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:99)
```

How can I fix this issue and initialize the driver correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your exception:

```
driver is not executable:
```

Make it executable

```
chmod +x geckodriver
```

And retry.

Comment: Question: which path we need to run this cmd ?

Comment: i got error after executing 
"chmod: cannot access 'geckodriver': No such file or directory"

Comment: @RajKumarSamala in the path where you have the geckodriver, of course.

Comment: i run the command on path geckodriver,
but still i get following error
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The driver is not executable: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/BackLogin/drivers/linux-driver/geckodriver
Code:
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "drivers/linux-driver/geckodriver");

Comment: (chmod +x geckodriver) doesn't work for me and this error is occurred: chmod: cannot access 'geckodriver': No such file or directory

Comment: Are you in the geckodriver's folder? Otherwise you should specify the path to the file in the command

Comment: You will need to type the command " chmod +x geckodriver " on the terminal where the geckodriver is unzipped and stored.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue when executing my tests using Java+Eclipse. I have added geckodriver under by project workspace, to make it simple just right-click the geckodriver in eclipse and check all the checkboxes under the Execute column (in properties window). This will make the geckodriver executable (otherwords you allow executable access to it)